# getting last distinct element Mongodb, mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a collection of the following schema:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("502e66f201f04e16a8885e8c"),
  "sensorID" : 2,    // id of the sensor
  "loc" : [3, 2],    // location of the sensor x,y
  "time" : new Date("Fri, 17 Aug 2012 19:44:50 GMT +04:00")   // time of the last meausurement
}
```

So there are few sensors in the network. They are moving and every x seconds they are telling server about their whereabouts.

I would like to find the last notified location of each sensor.

what I was trying to do:

```
db.runCommand({distinct: 'points', key: 'sensorID'})
```

to select all different sensors, but I can't figure out where should I put additional constrains for last time.

And the most important question. Should I actually do this in mongo. May be it is just better to use MySql

Comment: I was trying to do something similar and couldn't figure out how.  I ended up changing my data structure so that it stored a flag indicating it was the last update for that object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908287/find-the-first-item-for-each-distinct-object-in-a-sorted-query

Answer (score 0):

Are the sensors reporting at approximately the same time and is partially stale data tolerable?

Basically there are many ways to go about dealing with this problem.

One is, doing something similar to db.collection.find({}).sort( {time: -1}).limit( #Number of sensors#), which is effectively a MAX function on time, which will give you the most recent positions of the sensors. This approach however, will only work if all the sensors broadcast simultaneously, and is of course prone to partially stale data or duplicate data for one sensor, if one of the other sensors is particularly slow in reporting, such that the race condition where one sensor has updated twice since the slow sensors last update causing it to show up twice in the list, excluding the slow sensor. . One could remedy this by appending the distinct clause you have above, however this can still lead to potentially stale data, but at most a one off. If being one cycle behind every once in a while isn't a big deal, then this is plausible.

Another approach is querying for each sensor one at a time with something like

db.collection.find({ "sensorID : #sensorID#"}).sort( { time: -1}).limit(1);

Yet another approach, is changing your schema to have a "Most Recent" Flag. And when inserting a new sensor point and time, just query for the old "most recent" document for that sensor and update it to false. This involves a little bit of error handling since you never want a situation where there is no "most recent" and you are querying. So a better approach is to first set the new document you are inserting's flag to true. and then update the old documents flag to false. And then if you are searching for them one at a time between updates you can sort the two and add a limit of 1 to get the most recent. Else, if you want to search for all of them at once and get back a list of all the sensors, and it happens in between updates, you can run a distinct function on them and take a rough approximation for that sensor in this hopefully rare case.

Alternatively you can do this cleanly by adding a mapreduce function and grouping on sensors and filtering on time.

Hope this helps.